# web2py - display radio button into my form

Tags: web2py

i want to display a radio button into my from so i did:

```
 SQLField('active',requires=IS_IN_SET(('True','False')),widget=SQLFORM.widgets.radio.widget)
```

but it display an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'widget'
```

So how can fix it??

Is there any solution to display radio buttons into my from??
Thanks in advance

Neveen Adel

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
SQLField('active',requires=IS_IN_SET(['True','False']),widget=SQLFORM.widgets.radio.widget)
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running a very old web2py version. Please bring this up on the web2py mailing list.